# why is norton 360 quarantining android sdk as a threat?

Tags: windows-7, norton-360

I am very confused by Norton-360 behavior on Windows 7 lately.

Norton (22.5.0.124) is putting into quarantine things seemingly at random - android sdk, rstudio, uninstallers, MSI files that came preinstalled on my notebook.

(I learned about this the hard way after my android sdk vanished. I ended up uninstalling the sdk and now have to waste time reinstalling it.)

Is there a way to fix this behavior? (Or, are these really infected?) I don't want to disable the anti virus completely.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because Norton is the worst av software in the Universe.

Comment: @Moab, I respect your opinion, but reading it cost me a couple of minutes and left no wiser

Comment: Uninstall it and get a real AV.

Comment: @Moab instead of just making fly-by comments, why don't you provide a real answer if you know? And if you know a real AV, why don't you suggest one? This is so out of character of SO!!

Comment: Its a well known fact that McAfee is more malware than AV, has been since 2003